# Symfony EntityType with additional Data in request, TransformationFailedException

Tags: php, forms, symfony, types, request

i have the following problem. I'm using Symfony 3 and the FOSRestBundle. On request (PUT) i want to store an entity with some foreign keys (reference entities).
The request payload is in JSON format and i created some custom formtypes to get them automatically matched to entities. This works in most of the cases.

In some cases i dont want to have the referenced entity to be changed by the request and i have some additional info in the request to.

I think that i have to use the formtype `EntityType` as this would react like a select of an existing entity. But using this it only works if the payload (json) of the request just have a simple attribute with value. In my case i get a attribute with json-object in which the `id` exists with some other informations.
In this case the FormValidator throws an error telling:

`This value is not valid.` with `ConstraintViolation` and `TransformationFailedException` with message `All choices submitted must be NULL, strings or ints.`.

Is there a way to use one of the `Datatransformers` like e.g. `Viewtransformer` or the `Modeltransformer` to handle this case?

JSON-Request, `mask` attribute is causing the error

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "duration": 10,
   "mask": {
      "id": 218,
      "name": "Mask1",
      "maskElement": {
         "id": 472,
         "x" : 123,
        }
    }
}
```

SlideType Formtype which uses the `Mask` entity

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder->add("id", TextType::class, ["mapped" => false])
   ->add("duration")
   ->add('mask',EntityType::class,
      [
         "class" => Mask::class,
         "allow_extra_fields" => true,
         "query_builder" => function(MaskRepository $maskRepository){
               return $maskRepository->createQueryBuilder("m");
            }
      ]);
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I face the same problem using sf3.